# MATLAB: datestr char results to vector

Tags: string, matlab

I have a char string of dates that I need to convert to a matrix where each date is a field. Example:

```
>> f=SomeFunction(datestr(ReBalDates))

ans =

31-Jan-2006
28-Feb-2006
31-Mar-2006
30-Apr-2006
31-May-2006
30-Jun-2006
31-Jul-2006
31-Aug-2006

>> f(3)

ans =

31-Mar-2006
```

The above of course is the case I would like to end up with. When actually doing `f(3)` (less the imaginary function) I get:

```
>> f(3)

ans =

3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if have is a string array, so f(3) is the 3rd element, counting from top row, so it is the first character of line #3. What you wanted is to convert that into cell, so let's make your character array here:

```
a = ['31-Jan-2006'; '28-Feb-2006'; '31-Mar-2006']
```

Accessing `a(3)` still gives you `3` like before, but if you converted `a` into a cell string array, as

```
b = cellstr(a)

'31-Jan-2006'
'28-Feb-2006'
'31-Mar-2006'
```

Then you can access the 3rd cell as `b{3}`, which should give you what you wanted.

```
b{3}

ans =

31-Mar-2006
```